# Are PINSRB and PEXTRB faster or slower than MOV?

Tags: assembly, optimization, x86-64, micro-optimization, avx512

I want to store a byte integer array in either a memory location or in a xmm register.  To access each byte in that array from memory, I would use:

```
lea rdi,[memory_array]
mov al,[rdi]
mov [rdi],al
```

To access that each byte in that array from a xmm register, I would use:

```
pextrb al,xmm0,0 (or pextrb al,xmm0,1, etc).  
pinsrb xmm0,al,0 (or pinsrb al,xmm0,1, etc).
```

According to Agner Fog's instruction tables for Skylake:

```
MOV (to al) has 1 uop fused, 2 uops unfused, and p23 p0156 uops each port, no latency and 0.5 reciprocal throughput.  

PINSRB has 2 uops fused, 2 uops unfused, and 2p5 uops each port, 3 latency and 2 reciprocal throughput.  

PEXTRB has 2 uops fused, 2 uops unfused, p0 p5 uops each port, 3 latency and 1 reciprocal throughput.
```

On its face it looks like PINSRB and PEXTRB are slower than MOV, but I'm not sure I'm reading it right.  I thought register-to-register operations are generally faster than memory moves.   Is my conclusion that the zmm-to-GP register moves are slower than memory moves correct based on the stats above?

Comment: `mov al,[rdi]` - You normally don't want to merge with the old value of RAX; that creates a false dependency.  Agner Fog's insn tables don't have sensible numbers for load latency, only the round trip.  Also, **an empty latency field in Agner's tables doesn't mean 0 latency, it means he didn't measure it!!**  There's L1d load-use latency (or store-forwarding latency), and the [ALU merge latency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45660139/how-exactly-do-partial-registers-on-haswell-skylake) because you wrote a byte register instead of using `movzx` like a compiler out.

Comment: Also, `pinsrb` and `pextrb` take dword GP register operands like EAX, not AL.  And yes they're slow for throughput; if you want a lot of separate bytes, vector store / movzx reload.  Not totally clear what you're comparing, though; a buffer in memory vs. an XMM register are not usually equivalent for doing other things with them.

Comment: As it's possible to loop through an xmm register with the PINSR/PEXTR instructions, that would work to store an array in an xmm register, but as I suspected (and I think you have confirmed) it looks like a memory array would simply be faster than using  PINSR/PEXTR to access elements of an array.  The idea is faster access, but it looks like that's not what will happen.

Comment: It's not possible to loop with pins/extr instructions.  The index has to be immediate, not a loop counter.  If you need to do something scalar to all 16 / 32 / 64 byte elements of a vector reg, it's usually faster to use memory and eat the store-fowarding stall for the final vector reload.  But if you just need one or two elements, `pextr` and/or `pinsr` are good.

Comment: That answers my question. Thanks for the comments.